# C++ primer 5th ed. assigning to an std::array from a brace-list

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello I am on page 1286 of C++ primer. I am at the solutions part. here is an example in the book:

> ```
>  std::array<int, 10> a1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
>  std::array<int, 10> a2 = {0}; // elements all have value 0
>  a1 = a2; // replace elements  in a1
>  a2 = {0}; // error: cannot assign to an array from a braced list
> ```

- However we can assign to an `std::array` from a braced list so `a2` is assigned `0` to the first element and all the remaining elements are value-init to `0` too.
- So is this a mistake in the book or just because of some change in the new Standard? Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into the 6th edition of C++ Primer? The main selling point of the 5th edition when it came out was it covered the relatively new and uncovered C++11. That was 10 years ago. 10 very busy years.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say the the 5th edition was probably done in tandem with C++11 being finalized. Some things were probably changed and the authors didn't take notice. Maybe there was a defect report or two in the time since, who knows. This is valid C++11, even the line marked as an error.

Comment: clang 4 gives warnings [here](https://godbolt.org/z/89KKWdxsM) but gcc 4.9 does not.  I'm thinking it was a brace elision issue that was a DR or fixed before published

Comment: Looks about right, @StoryTeller . I have to go back to GCC4.7 for the assignment to not compile. [Here's my mock-up on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dxbE6Y668)

Comment: @user4581301 - Your mock up also verifies it's likely the brace elision thing Nathan hypothesized. Replacing `{0}` by `{{0}}` makes GCC 4.7 happy too.

Comment: @user4581301: Where can I find C++ primer 6th edition? I've search on Amazaon but got the message: "out of stock". Would you recommend a link? thank you!

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Looks like we're both out of luck. Not officially released until middle of next year. Unless you have Academic friends who have a prerelease draft you aren't getting a copy yet. I'll just shut up about it for the next six months or so.